# What is the best way to inherit a struct in Rust 1.3?

Tags: inheritance, struct, rust

When I compile this with Rust 1.3, the compiler tells me that `virtual` structs have been removed from the language:

```
struct Foo: Bar {

}
```

Comment: http://aturon.github.io/blog/2015/09/18/reuse/ has a few working examples from Servo if you really need the inheritance.

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756315/how-to-program-shared-behaviors-in-rust-without-repeating-same-code-in-each-modu/68757050#68757050  prefers composition over inheritance

Answer (score 24):

Short answer, you can't do inheritance with structs.

Instead of inheritance, Rust uses composition. However, you *can* do inheritance within [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html). Traits don't have data, but they can define functions, so you can many of the benefits of inheritance by using them:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

trait FooBar: Foo {
    fn foobar(&self);
}
```

An implementor of `FooBar` *must* implement `foo` (unless you provide a default implementation).

One way Rust does specialization is typically through `enums`, which are very powerful in Rust. One of the Rust developers wrote [a good blog series about how Rust approaches these types of problems](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/05/05/where-rusts-enum-shines/). I recommend reading through it as well as reading through the official book.