# How do I avoid code duplication in similar methods which differ in small amounts at many points?

Tags: rust, duplicates, code-duplication

I have a very data driven program which contains different types of entities having very similar structures and differing only in specific places.

For example, every entity has a name which can be changed. Here's [two example methods](https://gist.github.com/Folling/239a1c24725799752603a64d44c4ecca) to demonstrate how the methods might be similar:

```
pub fn rename_blueprint(
    &mut self,
    ctx: &mut Context,
    db_handle: &Transaction,
    blueprint_id: Uuid,
    new_name: &str,
) -> Result<(), DataError> {
    ctx.debug(format!(
        "Renaming blueprint {} to {}",
        blueprint_id, new_name
    ));
    self.assert_blueprint_exists(ctx, db_handle, blueprint_id)?;
    let mut stmt = db_handle
        .prepare("UPDATE `blueprints` SET `name` = ? WHERE `id` == ?")
        .on_err(|_| ctx.err("Unable to prepare update statement"))?;
    let changed_rows = stmt
        .execute(params![new_name.to_string(), blueprint_id])
        .on_err(|_| ctx.err("Unable to update name in database"))?;
    if changed_rows != 1 {
        ctx.err(format!("Invalid amount of rows changed: {}", changed_rows));
        return Err(DataError::InvalidChangeCount {
            changes: changed_rows,
            expected_changes: 1,
        });
    }
    ctx.blueprint_renamed(blueprint_id, new_name);
    Ok(())
}

pub fn rename_attribute(
    &mut self,
    ctx: &mut Context,
    db_handle: &Transaction,
    attribute_id: Uuid,
    new_name: &str,
) -> Result<(), DataError> {
    ctx.debug(format!(
        "Renaming attribute {} to {}",
        attribute_id, new_name
    ));
    self.assert_attribute_exists(ctx, db_handle, attribute_id)?;
    let mut stmt = db_handle
        .prepare("UPDATE `attributes` SET `name` = ? WHERE `id` == ?")
        .on_err(|_| ctx.err("Unable to prepare update statement"))?;
    let changed_rows = stmt
        .execute(params![new_name.to_string(), attribute_id])
        .on_err(|_| ctx.err("Unable to update name in database"))?;
    if changed_rows != 1 {
        ctx.err(format!("Invalid amount of rows changed: {}", changed_rows));
        return Err(DataError::InvalidChangeCount {
            changes: changed_rows,
            expected_changes: 1,
        });
    }
    ctx.attribute_renamed(attribute_id, new_name);
    Ok(())
}
```

The same method with almost identical code now needs to exist for 5-11 more types of entities. I can usually just replace `Blueprint` with the name of the other entity type, and it will all work. However, that seems like quite a silly solution.

Likewise, writing a helper method which accepts all relevant strings, methods, and such to call it seems similarly silly.

I don't believe I could even avoid this by passing in some "strategy" or other indirection helper (`EntityRenamer` or something similar), given that the logic would need to be coded there anyway. It'd just be moving the problem one step up.

It should be mentioned that this is one of the shorter methods. Entities can also be moved, deleted, created, etc. all of which have similar code - sometimes 30+ lines long.

[How to avoid code duplication of different structs with semantically equal fields/properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429218/how-to-avoid-code-duplication-of-different-structs-with-semantically-equal-field) does not solve my issue. That question basically asks "how to do inheritance, when no inheritance exists", whereas my code is struggling with collectivizing very similar logic into the lowest common denominator. Traits or common implementations won't solve my problem, as the code would still exist - it'd only be moved someplace else.

How would you go about deduplicating this code?

I'm more looking for guidelines than someone writing my code for me. A few possible solutions could be:

1. use macros and then just use something like `entity_rename_impl!(args)`
2. use a helper method with a different parameter for each specific thing that can differ from function to function
3. don't try to abstract the entire method, and instead focus on writing helper functions for smaller things, so that the methods might be duplicating, but it's very little code that is abstracted elsewhere

A MCVE ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f317adac0da81db6a8febc5814b33fb8)):

```
#![allow(unused)]

pub struct Transaction {}

impl Transaction {
    pub fn execute_sql(&self, sql: &str) -> i32 {
        // .. do something in the database
        0
    }

    pub fn bind_id(&self, id: Uuid) {}
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Uuid {}

impl std::fmt::Display for Uuid {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "mockup")
    }
}

pub fn assert_blueprint_exists(blueprint_id: Uuid) {}

pub fn track_blueprint_rename(id: Uuid, new_name: String) {}

pub fn assert_attribute_exists(blueprint_id: Uuid) {}

pub fn track_attribute_rename(id: Uuid, new_name: String) {}

pub fn rename_blueprint(
    db_handle: &Transaction,
    blueprint_id: Uuid,
    new_name: &str,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    println!("Renaming blueprint {} to {}", blueprint_id, new_name);
    assert_blueprint_exists(blueprint_id);

    db_handle.bind_id(blueprint_id);
    let changed_rows = db_handle.execute_sql("UPDATE `blueprints` SET `name` = ? WHERE `id` == ?");

    if changed_rows != 1 {
        println!("Invalid amount of rows changed: {}", changed_rows);
        return Err("Invalid change count in blueprint rename".to_string());
    }

    track_blueprint_rename(blueprint_id, new_name.to_string());

    Ok(())
}

pub fn rename_attribute(
    db_handle: &Transaction,
    attribute_id: Uuid,
    new_name: &str,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    println!("Renaming attribute {} to {}", attribute_id, new_name);
    assert_attribute_exists(attribute_id);

    db_handle.bind_id(attribute_id);
    let changed_rows = db_handle.execute_sql("UPDATE `attributes` SET `name` = ? WHERE `id` == ?");

    if changed_rows != 1 {
        println!("Invalid amount of rows changed: {}", changed_rows);
        return Err("Invalid change count in attribute rename".to_string());
    }

    track_attribute_rename(attribute_id, new_name.to_string());

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: _"The code is almost identical"_ — The exact meaning of "almost" here makes all the difference. Perhaps show some examples and explain exactly how the methods are the same - and how they are different.

Comment: @Shepmaster Given that this is a question about semantics, less so about an error or an invalidity I don't see how a MVCE would help at all.
The question is also agnostic towards the types, traits, or fields used in my code.
@PeterHall As aforementioned, replacing every `blueprint` with the name of any other type is how they differ mostly. Though I added an example for the same function with a different type, since I agree with the sentiment that it makes it clearer to see my exact issue - thank you!

Comment: Adjusted my code accordingly.

Comment: I'm more looking for guidelines than someone writing my code for me.
A few possible solutions would e.g. be:
1. use macros and then just use something like `entity_rename_impl!(args)`

2. use a helper method with a different parameter for each specific thing that can differ from function to function

3. don't try to abstract the entire method, and instead focus on writing helper functions for smaller things, so that the methods might be duplicating, but it's very little code that is abstracted elsewhere

I was hoping to get some insights on the best practices, than a premade solution.

Comment: *is how they differ mostly* — that "mostly" is **incredibly important**. If you [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff) your two pieces of code, you will see that there are important semantic differences. For example, your blocks of code have different conditionals in the SQL which go beyond just the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209783/discussion-between-folling-and-shepmaster).

Answer (score 0):

The way I generally solve this kind of problem is by using generics. Let the caller choose the appropriate type.

```
trait Entity {
    fn desc(&self) -> String;
}

impl Entity for Blueprint {
    // ...
}

pub fn rename<T>(/* ... */)
where
    T: Entity,
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Rust doesn't have templates, but even with templates - how would they solve this specific situation? Could you perhaps provide an example? The issue here isn't choosing the type, but rather choosing the appropriate string-bits and methods to use alongside the main method.

Comment: Sorry for using c++ jargon. I meant generics in rust. One of the way is to write a generic function that accepts a generic type parameter T with a trait bound. Let all the entities implement that trait bound.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the code duplication issue though, it'd only change where the code is written - I'd still need to write one implementation for all renaming functions, even though they're fundamentally very similar

Comment: @Folling why wouldn't it remove the duplication? The common / repeated code is in the function `rename` once, the different code is in each trait implementation. Where does the duplication remain?

Comment: The `rename` function would need to contain pretty much everything that is already contained in the different `rename_*` functions at the moment, hence there would still be a lot of duplication, it'd only be in `impl`s instead of the current methods

Comment: @Folling there'd only be a single `rename` function instead of many `rename_*` functions. *Only* the differences would belong in each trait implementation. There would be no duplication.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the point however. The current issue is that it's hard to trace the answers to the questions "which table should be used", "which column should be used", "which functions should be called at the end to be stored in the context", "what entity name should be used in log messages". Neither of these seem to be solved by moving it into separate `impl`s