# Is there any way I can add custom functions to a predefined struct?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that is used by different functions. Instead of passing the struct as input to the different functions, I think I can implement the struct with all the functions that need to access it. However, there are certain fixed basic functions that I want to provide so that whenever the struct is created, I don't have to implement the same set of functions over and over again.

Put in another way, what I really want is the struct inheritance: I have certain set of methods associated with `struct` and user can add their custom functions to `struct` and allow them to access the data contained in data. Is there anyway able to do so?

Concretely, suppose I have a struct called `AppContext` and the fixed set of functions are `new` and `bdev_name`:

```
pub struct AppContext {
    bdev: *mut raw::spdk_bdev,
    bdev_desc: *mut raw::spdk_bdev_desc,
    bdev_io_channel: *mut raw::spdk_io_channel,
    buff: *mut c_char,
    bdev_name: *const c_char,
}

impl AppContext {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let context: AppContext;
        unsafe {
            context = mem::uninitialized();
        }
        context
    }

    pub fn bdev_name(&mut self, name: &str) {
        self.bdev_name = CString::new(name)
            .expect("Couldn't create a string")
            .into_raw()
    }
}
```

Now, when I use this struct, I do:

```
let mut context = AppContext::new();
context.bdev_name("Nvme0n1");
```

I want to add one extra function (say `end()`) that can work on the data within the context struct. However, `end()` is very domain specific function and needed in a specific module, and thus it's not a good idea to implement as part of the context struct.

Is there any way I can workaround the issue (i.e. add custom function to predefined `struct`)?

Comment: Your usage of `mem::uninitialized` is completely inappropriate and dangerous.

Comment: Your implementation of `bdev_name` easily creates memory leaks once it's called twice.

Comment: I'm new to Rust and I'm working on the FFI with some C library. For C, I can do `struct AppContext hello_context = {}`. I'm not sure what's the best way in Rust.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what memory leaks I can create and what's the approate way to implement it. I simply want to set some `char*` for the undelying C struct.

Comment: Presumably you should be setting those pointers to NULL so you know if they have been initialized or not. Uninitialized values can be *literally* any value that just happens to be in that chunk of memory at that point in time. Uninitialized memory is a classic door to allowing security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Shepmaster I take a look at links that you listed. If I use extension trait, I think I still need to reimplement the `new` and `bdev_name` methods in the extension trait implementation? Is there any way to simply inherit not reimplement? Thanks!

Comment: Rust has no inheritance ([What is the best way to inherit a struct in Rust 1.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32736170/155423) / [Is it possible for one struct to extend an existing struct, keeping all the fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32552593/155423) / [How to avoid code duplication of different structs with semantically equal fields/properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429218/155423)). I don't know why you think you need to reimplement the methods.