# How do I write functions that handle versioned data when Rust doesn't have inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, rust, semantic-versioning

I have data that is versioned using SemVer. I have functions that have SemVer requirements, e.g. they support versions in the half-open interval [1.1, 2.0). In C++ I could do something like this:

```cpp
struct Data_v1_0 {
  // Added in V1.0
  int a;
};

struct Data_v1_1 : public Data_v1_0 {
  // Added in V1.1
  int b;
}

void foo(const Data_v1_0& data) {
  // Supports [1.0, 2.0)
  print(data.a);
}

void bar(const Data_v1_1& data) {
  // Supports [1.1, 2.0)
  print(data.b);
}
```

Is there any way to do something similar in Rust?

Comment: If your struct has private fields, it can only be constructed from within your crate, so adding new fields is a backwards-compatible change anyway.

Comment: Why would you make a new class in C++ actually?

Comment: Try to avoid these kinds of invasive structural constraints. Rather, make your logic operate on the latest version of the data structure, and apply data migrations at the entry and exit points. As you add more versions, users of the oldest data structures will experience the most performance impact, while users of the newest format will experience zero impact. Your code will be clean because it only needs to support  the latest structures.

Comment: This seems like an unusual context to ask for inheritance, but that aside, the question is very similar to other questions such as [Is it possible for one struct to extend an existing struct, keeping all the fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552593/is-it-possible-for-one-struct-to-extend-an-existing-struct-keeping-all-the-fiel) If you have a question that isn't answered there, please [edit] your question to make it more specific.

Comment: Other questions about inheritance and Rust: [How to avoid code duplication of different structs with semantically equal fields/properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39429218/3650362) and [What is the best way to inherit a struct in Rust 1.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32736170/3650362)

Comment: Could you add a rationale why you would want data structures versioned like this? Looks insane to me, to be honest

Comment: Embedding one struct inside another, as your C++ code does, only seems to allow for *adding* new fields. Adding new fields is a semver-compatible change, so it doesn't seem like your proposed (current?) C++ solution best fits your own requirements.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Yes exactly. So if I load a `Data_V1_1` I can pass it to `foo()` and `bar()` but if I load a `Data_V1_0` I can only pass it to `foo`. That's how SemVer is supposed to work. I don't get your point to be honest.

Comment: So the desired solution never has to care about V2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use traits for this:

```rust
trait DataV1_0 {
    fn a(&self) -> i32;
}

trait DataV1_1: DataV1_0 {
    fn b(&self) -> i32;
}

struct Data {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

impl DataV1_0 for Data {
    fn a(&self) -> i32 {
        self.a
    }
}

impl DataV1_1 for Data {
    fn b(&self) -> i32 {
        self.b
    }
}

fn foo(data: &dyn DataV1_0) {
    println!("a: {}", data.a());
}

fn bar(data: &dyn DataV1_1) {
    println!("b: {}", data.b());
}
```

We use trait inheritance to replace the struct here and trait methods to access the fields. My example is read-only, but you can implement setter methods as well.

Comment: Hmm yes ok. Although with your solution there's technically no way to actually *make* a V1.0 `Data`. You can set `b` to a default value I guess, but then nothing prevents you accidentally passing your V1.0 `Data` to `bar()`.

Comment: So wouldn't you have to do `struct Data_v1_0s { a: i32, }  struct Data_v1_1s { a: i32, b: i32, }` and then `impl Data_v1_0 for Data_v1_0s {}` and `impl Data_v1_1 for Data_v1_0s {}` and `impl Data_v1_1 for Data_v1_1s {}`. That is going to get very tedious! Probably requires macros.

Comment: @Timmm you could easily implement a different struct that only implements `Data_v1_0`. That cannot be passed into `bar`.

Comment: I'd echo @peter-hall's comment on the question as well, that it's better off not having versioned data structures, but use data migrations. If you've ever worked with COM and versioned interfaces you'd appreciate the pain of maintaining this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to implement inheritance like it would be done in C. I'm not saying that you should do this, but that it's one possibility to consider:

```rust
pub struct Data_v1_0 {
    // Added in V1.0
    a: i32,
}

impl Data_v1_0 {
    fn a(&self) -> i32 {
        self.a
    }
    fn set_a(&mut self, a: i32) {
        self.a = a
    }
}

pub struct Data_v1_1 {
    extends: Data_v1_0,
    // Added in V1.1
    b: i32,
}

impl Data_v1_1 {
    fn b(&self) -> i32 {
        self.b
    }
    fn set_b(&mut self, b: i32) {
        self.b = b
    }
}

impl Deref for Data_v1_1 {
    type Target = Data_v1_0;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.extends
    }
}

impl DerefMut for Data_v1_1 {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.extends
    }
}
```

Thanks to `Deref` and `DerefMut`, you can call `a()` and `set_a()` on instances of `Data_v1_1`. However, calling it with the [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html#disambiguating-function-calls) (e.g. `Data_v1_1::a(data)`) is not possible, so replacing `Data_v1_0` with `Data_v1_1` would be an API breaking change.